# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type breeze.linalg.Vector[Int] is not supported

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe with column of type Array[Array[Int]], I am trying to add up the array values using breeze api, however I am getting a schema for type not supported error.

input dataset

```
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name |combined                                                                                                                                                             |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Bob  |[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]|
```

The implementation

```
import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.numerics._

def mVect = udf((arr: Array[Array[Int]]) =>arr.map(breeze.linalg.Vector(_)).reduce(_ + _))

result.select($"name", mVect($"combined")).show
```

Error

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type breeze.linalg.Vector[Int] is not supported

Answer (score 2):

Well, it happens because it indeed isn't supported.

There are different possible solutions, but the simplest one is to skip breeze completely:

```
def mVect = udf((arr: Array[Array[Int]]) => arr.transpose.map(_.sum))
```

Comment: well, I am not really looking for an alternate solution here, I was wondering why I am getting this error, when I try the same function on an ordinary array it works.

Comment: @Masterbuilder You get an exception exactly for the reason stated in the error message - `Schema for type breeze.linalg.Vector[Int] is not supported`. You can refer to [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) for the full list of supported types and type mappings.